# Copying files and deploying to Azure without building using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm attempting to deploy a web site to Azure using VSTS. Basically, I commit code to the GIT repo and have it setup to run CI, so it begins building as soon as I commit. However, once it hits the release section, it never copies the code to the Azure web app, rather, it gives me this line:

> Info: Updating file ({projectname}\error.txt).

It doesn't copy the files I changed, but rather always just copies this file. I checked and there is indeed an error.txt file in my website directory in Azure, but it is always blank.

This build/deploy process isn't "standard" because the build step only downloads from source code, it doesn't build, because the website isn't a "web application", but rather just a "web site", meaning it doesn't need to be built.

So my build step is as follows:

- Get Sources
- Run on Agent - this step is empty

so the idea is that it just downloads everything from source control, that's it.

Then, my release step is as follows:

- Artefacts are from build step above
- deploy to environment 1 (dev)
- Azure app service deploy, using "package or folder" as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably want a different working directory and point it to the Artefact directory. But the exact reason os going to be really hard to tell with the very limited information you've provided. Try running with the `systemdebug=true` variable enabled to get the extended log information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I actually figured this out and will leave this here in case anyone else needs it.

I admit I'm pretty new to the Azure/VSTS world, so maybe someone else is making my mistake as well.

If you don't need to "build" your project, then don't. I resolved it by simply skipping the build step altogether. What I was really after was to just download the files from source control and deploy them as-is.

In your release editor, you can specify which "artifact" you want to use to release, and one of the options is source control, which is what I did.

This would be useful for websites like mine where you don't need to build them (mine is DNN/DotNetNuke, so you don't build it before deploying).

Comment: You can accept your answer (click √ symbol on the left of your answer). answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: I would, but I can't yet :)

Comment: You can mark it now. Sorry for reminder that the own answer can be accepted after 48 hours posted.